# consultar com inner join no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, inner

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria solicitar vossa ajuda em algo que to quebrando a cabeça para resolver e não consigo arrumar para dar certo

**tenho 4 tabelas**

1. productos ->id | slug | titulo | info1 | info2 | info3
2. prodnutri -> idNutricion | idProducto | porcion | info2 | info3
3. prodpreparo -> idPreparo | idProducto | info1 | info2 | info3
4. prodingredientes -> idIngredientes | idProducto | info1 | info2
   |info3

as tabelas vão ter bastante informação e não queria deixar todo em uma só.. por isso acredito seja melhor fazer em dividir a informação para 4.

To tentando fazer na Model a consulta e to errando, já tentei varias maneira e não consigo..

eu consigo listar os produtos e chamar tudo certinho, desta maneira
dominio.com/produtos/ver/nome-do-produto

NA MODEL / ProductModel -- 
minha consulta basica onde consigo trazer todos os dados da tabela productos

```
 public function find($slug){      //
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    return $this->db->get('productos')->row();
}
```

porem ao tenar fazer o inner -- com uma tabela, porem precisso que seja com as 3 + tb produto, não consigo e da error.

```
public function find($slug){      //
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $this->db->select("productos.slug");
    $this->db->from('productos');
    $this->db->join('prodnutri', 'prodnutri.idNutricion = productos.slug');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $this->db->get('productos')->row();
}
```

NO CONTROLLER / produtos

```
public function ver($slug)
{   
    $this->load->view('incluir/cabecalho');
    $data['producto'] = $this->ProductModel->find($slug);
    $this->load->view('productos/producto', $data);
    $this->load->view('incluir/rodape');
}
```

O problema é que não to conseguindo fazer a consulta na model (Acredito que o controller esteja certo!
porque todos os dados do tabla produto ele traz certo, porem quando quero trazer os dados das outras tablas ele esta dando erro..

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$porcion

na view to usando o vetor assim

```
<?Php echo $producto->titulo;?> -- titulo da tb Productos
<?Php echo $producto->porcion;?> -- titulo da tb prodnutri
```

Alguém pode ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido em uma luz para resolver da tabela com inner join..

Comment: tenta dar um `var_dump($data['producto']);` após o `$data['producto']` no seu controller, que você ve exatamente o que está retornando.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta esta solução no método de consulta do seu MODEL:

```
try {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM productos p ".
        "INNER JOIN prodnutri pn INNER JOIN prodpreparo pp ".
        "INNER JOIN prodingredientes pin ".
        "ON (p.id = pn.idProducto AND p.id = pp.idProducto AND p.id = pin.idProducto)");

    if ($query === false) {
        throw new Exception($this->db->error()['message'], $this->db->error()['code']);
    }
    return $query->result();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    return null;
}
```

O retorno é em forma de array, assim você pode percorrer da forma desejada.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, vc ta chamando duas vezes o metodo `get`, pra mim ta errado:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
return $this->db->get('productos')->row();
```

vc nao ta usando essa primeira linha do `$query` pra nada.

Segundo, tenta dar um `var_dump($data['producto']);` após o `$data['producto']` no seu controller, que você ve exatamente o que está retornando. Se realmente teve resultado a busca.

Lembrando que $this->db->get('productos')->**row()**; retorna apenas um resultado e $this->db->get('productos')->**result()**; retorna um array.

De toda forma o var_dump() vai te ajudar.